# Implementing a set of web services with WCF using https without IIS

Tags: wcf, authentication, https

Trying to implement https on a WCF webservice which we are not running in IIS. Currently using the following code for each class and interface which describes and implements a service.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClass), "https://localhost:8085/ServiceClass");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServiceClass), binding, "");
host.Open();
```

The service starts without any exceptions, but when I try to connect a browser to :

```
https://localhost:8085/ServiceClass/Item?format=xml
```

I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. Additionally I hook host.Faulted and host.Closed and am not getting any error messages.

I can't find an example anywhere of implementing WCF web service over https using basic authentication, which is what we're looking for.

Comment: go to your browser and write https://localhost:8085/ServiceClass?wsdl ans see if you can get anything.

Comment: Same error as I was getting before.

Comment: try removing the binding and the AddServiceEndpoint.

Comment: I did, but now I get an exception when starting the WebServiceHost. Namely, 
"HTTP count not register https://+:8085/Instruments/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS."

I've tried checking to see if the address was already reserved using:

netsh http show urlacl

but there is nothing on port 8085